# Captive Portal on Raspberry Pi (raspbian) with Bridged Adapter

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi, iptables-redirect

I am trying to create a captive portal on a Raspberry Pi by following the steps from this GitHub project: https://github.com/thgh/pilon

I have 2 network interfaces on the pi.

- `wlan0` TP-Link TL-WN821N wifi Dongle (RTL based chipset- supports master mode)
- `eth0` Ethernet connected to the Gateway for internet access.

I have followed the steps outlined above to create an access point using hostapd, share the internet from `eth0` via a bridge adapter `br0` to `wlan0`. The access point works, users can connect and surf the internet.

Now I want to redirect the users to a splash page to authenticate them first (aka captive portal style) before allowing internet access. I have the iptable rules below and they don't seem to affect the bridge traffic.

Here are the iptable rules:

```
# Start from scratch
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Redirect to nginx server
iptables -t mangle -N internet
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80:50000 -j internet
iptables -t mangle -A internet -j MARK --set-mark 99
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m mark --mark 99 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.17:80
```

Appreciate any help in this regard,

Cheers.

Comment: You want `ebtables`, not `iptables` if you want to manage a bridge.